# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab;

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following a tutorial ([link](http://android2.in/how-to-upload-images-to-firebase-storage/)) to upload images to Firebase database but am getting the below error. I rechecked the gradle dependencies and also enabled  multidex support but error still remains

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzab;
    at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.paperwrrk.android.storageref.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:36)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzab" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-tubesock-0.0.11_74622aa9da17bf60443b34c100000d076f6631ba-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-25.0.0_416ca7aea2b0e15fba678c97c0d71c330758ffee-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-jackson-databind-2.2.2_169f7b55dddecf9b169deccb0ac50ee124eda962-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-jackson-core-2.2.2_3ae6e87b0280ab52f712dfb927e3401fe25aa21c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-jackson-annotations-2.2.2_dd21f43a23482b41eb5ed094fcce68c90eeb0ffd-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_e8156948d2eb9e5ed0b41cc1f9f830e7838bb3b5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_9056040795c4cf170b00cbf021bf976514542498-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_79b2045e82b81d2f064515f884990a3d2a9f29af-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_2879b3ac18601405060244958a8db64bdb3655f9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_1ce40cec84eadc9153f026cb869c8b1760c8461a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.paperwrrk.android.storageref/files/instant-run/dex/slice-firebase-client-jvm-2.3.1_764f8006
```

Gradle.app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.paperwrrk.android.storageref"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please tell what I'm doing wrong here!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

now here is the problem, you are using different versions in dependencies of gradle 
So change this

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

to this

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

one more thing is that now `com.firebae:firebase-client-android` is deprecated so you need to replace it with `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1`  and here is the documentation for that https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

Comment: I had similar issue with facebook account kit lib. and this solution worked like a charm! kudos!!

Comment: From gradle 3.0 on wards 'compile' is deprecated. Use 'Implementation' or 'Api' instead. Also 'testCompile' is deprecated, use 'testImplementation' instead.

Comment: this is good answer but in my case,my fault was using analytics library before it initialized. generally using a class(library) that not initialized makes this error

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar problem while implementing native ad and killed almost 4 hours...

At last i have figured out that there are  different  com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads  version in different module('17.1.1' and '12.0.0').

After changing all version to 17.1.1 it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeking solution for react-native project, make sure there is same version used among different modules and replace "+" with some latest available version.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time the problem is in the gradle. I had a similar problem until I changed firebase-(storage/auth/database) build gradle for module app to be the same for e.g.
( com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0,com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0, com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0)