# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbr

Tags: java, android, ffi, firebase-analytics, temenos-quantum

I am trying to write a Firebase Analytics [FFI](http://docs.kony.com/6_5/konylibrary/studio/studio_user_guide/Content/Foreign_Function_Interface_JS.htm) for Kony application, below is the error message I am getting while running application in Android device.

Need to identity the library which has zzbr class file.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: com.example.konyanalyticsdemo, PID: 8451
Error Code: 605 Error Name: null Message: Error in JavaScript callback invocation at Handler.js:2
FFINamespace.logEvent("101", "Event1", "Text");
Uncaught KonyError:
errorCode : 605
name : Unknown Error
message : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbr;
JS Stacktrace:
at logEvent1 (Handler.js:2:18)
at Home_btnLog1_onClick_seq0 (Home.js:3:15)
at com.konylabs.vmintf.KonyJavaScriptVM.a(Unknown Source)
at com.konylabs.android.G.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at com.konylabs.android.F.run(Unknown Source)
[ 08-25 03:42:46.624   743: 1469 D/audio_hw_primary ]
select_devices: done
```

[image: Added Libs]

Comment: Will you show your build file??

Comment: where is the build file located ?

Comment: @UpendraShah have any idea on jar file which contains zzbr.class ?package name is com/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbr

Comment: I think it need google play service library

Comment: which build system are you using to manage dependencies? Ant or gradle?  If you are not using gradle to handle dependencies, start using it. And if you are using gradle, make sure that dependencies are of same version.  Here   similar issue is addressed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322864/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-failed-resolution-of-lcom-goo?rq=1